# PHP mailing address preg_match() not working

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to make a regular expression to match this mailing address:

> 4F 50 Adele Street 01234 London

Here is my code:

```
if( !(preg_match('/[1-9]{5}[A-Za-z] [1-9] [A-Za-z\.]+ [A-Za-z\.]+ [0-9]{5} [A-Za-z\.]+/', $address))){
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have `[1-9]{5}` at the beginning of the regexp. That matches exactly 5 digits, but you only have 1 digit before `F`.

Comment: I've regretfully downvoted, as you received a really thorough answer from grebneke, which must have taken some time to write, but you neither replied nor voted. Please do reply to respondents here, especially when a great effort has been obviously expended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this RE:

```
/[1-9][a-z] [1-9][0-9] [a-z.]+ [a-z.]+ [0-9]{5} [a-z.]+/i
```

Changes:

- There's only 1 digit at the beginning, I removed `{5}`
- The second number has 2 digits, I changed `[1-9]` to `[1-9][0-9]`
- You don't have to escape `.` inside brackets
- Instead of `A-Za-z`, I just write `a-z` and use the `i` modifier to make it case insensitive

[DEMO](http://regexr.com?37r5l)

Answer (score 1):

**You might need a more robust solution**

```
4F 50 Adele Street 01234 London
```

- `4F`: Always a single digit and a single character? Or could it be `14B`?
- `50`: Always two digits? Or any number of digits, like `1234` or `8`?
- `Adele Street`: Always two words containing only letters? Or could it be `Smith's Broad Street`?
- `01234`: Always exactly five digits?
- `London`: Always one word? Or could it be `Little Winging`?

**Here is one example** (but there are many ways to do it!)

```
preg_match("/\d+[a-z]\s+\d+\s+\D+\s+\d{5}\s+\S+/i", $address);
```

**Let's go through it**

"Match any number of digits `\d+` followed by a letter `a-z`, one or more whitespace `\s+`, any number of digits `\d+`, one or more whitespace `\s+`, one or more of anything **not** a digit `\D+`, one or more whitespace `\s+`, exactly five digits `\d{5}`, one or more whitespace `\s+`, one or more of anything **not**  whitespace `\S+`"

- `\d` matches a digit, same as `[0-9]`
- `\D` matches anything not a digit, same as `[^0-9]`
- `\s` matches whitespace
- `\S` matches anything not whitespace
- `+` after something means *match one or more*
  *`/i` at the end makes the whole pattern case insensitive

**The example assumes**

- First part is digit(s) and a letter
- Second part is digit(s)
- Street could be anything except a digit `\D+`
- Zip code is always five digits `\d{5}`
- City is anything starting with non whitespace `\S+` (could be more words after, we stop matching on the first)

Feel free to ask questions or comment. There are many ways to handle problems like this, depending on the data you are wrestling with!